# d3: Why does this function not remove elements?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, d3.js

Working in d3, I've got a function call that correctly draws a bar chart, but it doesn't update it correctly. Here's the important part of my code:

```
  # Drawing Elements
  @svg = d3.select(@s).append('svg').attr('width',@w).attr('height',@h)
  @rects = @svg.selectAll('rect')
  @labels = @svg.selectAll('text')

  drawRects: (data) ->
    rects = @rects.data(data)
    rects.enter().append('rect')
    rects.exit().remove()
    rects.attr('x', (d,i) => this.xScale(i) )
      .attr('y', (d) => @h - this.yScale(d) )
      .attr('width', @w / @data.length - @pad)
      .attr('height', (d) => this.yScale(d) )
      .attr('fill','#FFC05C')


  drawLabels: (data) ->
    labels = @labels.data(data)
    labels.enter().append('text')
    labels.exit().remove()
    labels.text( (d) -> d )
      .attr('text-anchor','middle')
      .attr('x', (d,i) => this.xScale(i) + ((@w / @data.length - @pad)/2) )
      .attr('y', (d) => @h - this.yScale(d) + 15 )
      .attr('fill','white')

  update: (data) ->
    this.drawRects(data)
    this.drawLabels(data)
```

When I initially set the graph I create some data (in this case an array of 20 numbers) and call the draw methods:

```
data = [1..20]
this.drawRects(data)
this.drawLabels(data)
```

The graphs are drawn correctly.

However, if these methods are called a second time, to update the data, the new data is placed in the DOM, but the old data is left behind as well, so it's just making a whole new set of elements.

What am I doing wrong here that's keeping `.exit()` from removing the old DOM elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reselect the `rect` and `text` elements and assign them the new data:

```
drawRects: (data) ->
    rects = @svg.selectAll('rect').data(data)
    #...

drawLabels: (data) ->
    labels = @svg.selectAll('text').data(data)
    #...
```

In your code you always assign the new data to the old (empty) `@rect` and (empty) `@labels` collections. And the data will be treated as "entered" for these empty collections and thus new elements will be created and nothing will be removed.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks! Just a comment to help anyone else learn what I learned: the issue is I was setting the selector as a variable before data entered the DOM, and then reusing that variable for the other methods. I needed to reselect the dom since there was now content on it.